# Prevent "^C" from being printed when aborting editing current prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal

When you're editing a prompt in bash, and then press Ctrl-C to abort it, "^C" might get printed where the cursor has been.

When you were in the middle of the line, this makes copy'n'pasting more difficult and IIRC it can be configured to not display it (and overwrite parts of the command line).

I do not have this problem myself (using zsh, which does not print "^C"), but ran across this in a Konsole bug report.

Comment: this happens to me in the current Ubuntu 10.04 under gnome-terminal and on an actual VT.  i haven't fully tested, but it doesn't happen in the same gnome-terminal when SSH'd into a Debian system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
stty -ctlecho
```

You can add that to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: checking with *stty -a* indicates the **echoctl** option is set; the manpage verifies **echoctl** and **ctlecho** are synonyms; running this command unsets the option.  thanks!

Comment: This works, but is probably a more general setting than only for this special case (aborting the command editing), isn't it?

Comment: @blueyed: Yes, it's more general.

Comment: @blueyed: i checked my bash's current *readline* settings for C-c, but found nothing.  this is the only thing i've found that affects the issue, but maybe someone else will know of a more targetted fix.

Comment: @quack quixote: There aren't any readline variables that affect this and though you can bind ^C to a readline function or macro but it won't do anything because the terminal driver controls its function.

Comment: @Dennis: yeah, that's what it looked like to me, thanks for verifying.  if i understand correctly, ^C is interpreted by the terminal driver as sending SIGINT, which you can trap with *trap*, or reassign with *stty intr NEWCHAR* ...

Comment: @quack quixote: That's correct.