# Mac Terminal.app: Force '^C' to be printed when editing current prompt, then aborting it

Tags: macos, unix, bash, shell, terminal.app

This is the opposite of [Prevent “^C” from being printed when aborting editing current prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/146815/prevent-c-from-being-printed-when-aborting-editing-current-prompt).

I'm using Bash. When I'm editing the commandline in Bash, and I hit Control-C to abort the commandline, the '^C' character does not display. I would like to see this character.

I tried commands like `stty -ctlecho` and `stty ctlecho` (which I borrowed from the other question), but this didn't work for me. <strike>This behavior seems to be true with my environment on Ubuntu, CentOS and MacOSX.</strike> This only happens within Apple's Terminal.App. If I SSH to a remote Linux or FreeBSD box, then `^C` is printed. So, this is clearly just a local setting.

**Update:**

Here is the output of `stty -a`, as requested by @quack quixote :

```
$ stty -a
speed 9600 baud; 41 rows; 88 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
 -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
 -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
 -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
 -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
 eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
 min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
 stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

After typing `stty sane`, `stty -a` will output the following. The only difference is the parameter of `-iutf8`.

```
$ stty sane
$ stty -a
speed 9600 baud; 41 rows; 157 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel -iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

Comment: if you haven't tried **"stty echoctl"**, do so.  "echoctl" should be synonymous with "ctlecho", but on some systems it may not be.  check both to make sure.  if you that doesn't help, please post the output of **"stty -a"** into your question.

Comment: How are you accessing these systems? PuTTY, gnome-terminal, xterm, console?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson : I'm using the Apple Terminal.App, and I'm either on the local system or I am SSH'd into a remote system. I think this happens with gnome-terminal as well, but I'm not certain.

Comment: It sounds like this may be specific to Terminal.app. I don't have access to a Mac right now, so I can't check on this. Have a look at the configuration options for Terminal.app to see if you can find something relevant.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: You are correct. This only happens on Terminal.App. Gnome Terminal works fine.

Comment: @Stefan: If you do `stty sane` do you get the same results from `stty -a` afterwards compared to what you posted above? It seems odd, but *many* of the settings are opposite mine in a PuTTY->Ubuntu session (each of brkint, echo, echoe, icanon, imaxbel, ixany).

Comment: @Dennis: I did a `stty sane`, and then a `stty -a`. I added the output to my question. The only difference seems to be a parameter of `-iutf8`.

Answer (score 1):

Just compared my outputs with yours from "stty -a" both with and without stty sane and come to the same conclusion: only difference is -iutf8.

However, for me the ^C does get printed when terminating a running command with CTRL + C on my MBP, running 10.6.4:

uname -a
Darwin noname 10.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0: Fri Apr 23 18:28:53 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.7.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Aesthir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6674482) on a related question, I came up with the [following](https://github.com/jasoncodes/dotfiles/commit/fe655e364e318cb7bbaf9d1b5e472be573d65165) which works great on both my OS X 10.8 and Debian machines:

```
trap '{ echo -n "^C" >&2; }' SIGINT
stty -echoctl
```